# Does frequency equal mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

If e equals mass and if frequency equals energy then is it correct to conclude that frequency equals mass?

Comment: You’re thinking about units in which $\hbar$ and $c=1$. This substitution does not mean that energy has the same units as mass and frequency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Many physicists use [natural units](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) and as such equations like $E=mc^2$ and $E=\hbar\omega$ where the physical constants $c=1$ and $\hbar=1$ implies that energy has units of mass and inverse time (frequency). So within this framework, you’d say that mass has units of inverse time.

Note that this is done for convenience and does not reflect the real physical dimensions of such quantities.

Answer (score -2):

Energy is related to mass by a proportionality constant. Frequency (of a photon) is related to energy (of a photon) by a proportionality constant. Being related by a proportionality constant does not mean being the same thing, it just means that those things exist in a fixed ratio.

Suppose you have twice as many kilograms of coconuts (c) as you have dogs (d): $c = A d$ where $A = 2kg$ Does that mean dogs are coconuts? Of course not.

Comment: To me the 2nd paragraph of your response seems at best unnecessary